# XPath results based on two nodes

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have XML that has a lot of duplicated values. I'd like to select all the rows with a specific section ("`sec`") and section tag ("`sec_tag`"), but I can't seem to get the XPath correct.

Here's a small snippet of the XML:

```
<root>
    <record>
        <sec>5</sec>
        <sec_tag>919</sec_tag>
        <nested_tag>
            <info>Info</info>
            <types>
                <type>1</type>
                <type>2</type>
                <type>3</type>
            </types>
        </nested_tag>
        <flags>00000000</flags>
    </record>

    <record>
        <sec>5</sec>
        <sec_tag>930</sec_tag>
        <nested_tag>
            <info>Info</info>
            <types>
                <type>1</type>
                <type>2</type>
                <type>3</type>
            </types>
        </nested_tag>
        <flags>00000000</flags>
    </record>
    <record>
        <sec>7</sec>
        <sec_tag>919</sec_tag>
        <nested_tag>
            <info>Info</info>
            <types>
                <type>1</type>
                <type>2</type>
                <type>3</type>
            </types>
        </nested_tag>
        <flags>00000000</flags>
    </record>
</root>
```

I want the node that has `<sec>5</sec>` and `<sec_tag>919</sec_tag>`.

I tried something like this:

```
//sec[text(), "5"] and //sec_tag[text(), "919"]
```

Obviously that's not the correct syntax there, I just need to find the correct XPath expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following XPath expression to return `record` elements having child `sec` equals `5` and `sec_tag` equals `919` :

```
//record[sec = 5 and sec_tag = 919]
```

Comment: PERFECT! I knew I was trying to over complicate it!